# File upload from a form on Laravel 4

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

I tried to use the `Input::upload()` method, which was available at L3, but I get an error message `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::upload()`

Is there a replacement? How does one handle file uploads from a form with L4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It now should be `Input::file()`

as stated in the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#files